# AngularJS and Restangular: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular

I built a service and this service return an object. But, in my controller i don't work with this object because '.then' dont't work.

My service:

```
var getUser = function(userId) {

    Restangular.all(userId).post(JSON.stringify()).then(function(response) {
        var obj = angular.fromJson(response);
        if (!obj.isError) {
            return obj;
        }
        else {
            console.log("ERRO getUserCard");
        }
    });
};
```

My controller:

```
var succsess = function(data){
    welcomeScope.getUser = data;
    console.log("getUser: " + welcomeScope.getUser);
};

var error = function(){
    console.log("Erro error");
};

function loadProfile(){ 
    welcomeSvc.getUser("203831").then(success,error);
};
```

Note: `welcomeScope` is my $scope.

Comment: `getUser` function must return a promise for `.then` in the controller to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add return in function getUser

```
var getUser = function(userId){
   return Restangular.all(userId).post(JSON.stringify()).then(function(response){
        var obj = angular.fromJson(response);
        if (!obj.isError) {
            return obj;
        }
        else{
            console.log("ERRO getUserCard");
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getUser() function needs to return a promise:

```
var getUser = function(userId) {

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  Restangular.all(userId).post(JSON.stringify()).then(function(response) {
    var obj = angular.fromJson(response);
    if (!obj.isError) {
        resolve(obj);
    }
    else {
        reject(console.log("ERRO getUserCard"));
    }
  })
 })
};
```

You may need to pass resolve, reject into Restangulars promise